# How does $\mathrm{Res}_{\{I\}}\chi = \mathbb{I} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{I}$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

My definition of restriction is: Let $H < G$, $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$. The restriction of $\rho$ to $H$, $\rho: H \rightarrow GL(V)$. Its character is
$$Res_H\chi(h)=\chi(h) \ \ \forall h \in H$$

How does $\mathrm{Res}_{\{I\}}\chi = \mathbb{I} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{I}$?

Firstly I cannot see how to restrict wrt to a representation (ie $\mathbb{I}$) rather than a subgroup.

I think this may have something with a lack of understanding between the correspondence between the presentations of representations, ie as a vector space or as map/matrix.

Comment: I believe $\operatorname{Res}_{\{I\}}\chi$ means the restriction to the trivial subgroup $\{I\}\subset G$. Since every representation of $\{I\}$ is trivial, the assertion follows.